# Profiling existing flash files

Tags: apache-flex, profiling, flash

I'm trying to do some research on flash objects in browsers. For example memory usage etc.
With Adobe Flex Builder 3 im trying to do some profiling on swf files but the problem is that I can only do this on debug swfs. Almost all adds/games/video are release version. Is there a way to some testing on those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357825/flash-actionscript-cpu-profiler), posting in here too as it's just as relevant in this thread:
It's important to note that the Flash Player implementation is different on each platform and to an extent each browser, so expect notable speed differences. So if you're developing a resource intensive application you should be using profiling tools specific to each OS you're targeting, like for example [Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/technology/tools.html) on OS X and of course test the performance in each browser.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you will need to get the source. You could try a [decompiler](http://theflashblog.com/?p=352).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [flash.sampler](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/sampler/package.html). You will need to run your content in the debugging version of the Flash *player*, but the content itself doesn't need to have been compiled with debugging symbols.

You can use the **PreloadSWF** option to inject an agent that can monitor. If you just want memory usage, that's a cheap API to call.