# CPU usage in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, cpu, utilization

I have a large project with lots of classes. It takes 40% CPU when it is running. What is the best way to find out what operations and functions are responsible for the load? I am using Flash Builder 4.5 AS3 Project. Built-in profiler doesn't help me much. Thanks

Comment: How you're running your SWF can also make a difference. You can choose between the standalone player or the browser plugin. Additionally, make sure that only one Flash instance is open - I don't know if it's the same with CPU usage, but Flash will report total memory usage (instead of usage per SWF), so it's something to watch for.

Comment: What is your app doing? Is it animating a lot of things? It is possible this is just the rendering. If you don't have a lot of animation happening, then you need to consider anything that happens over and over, like enterframe handlers, timers and loops.

Comment: Just do what Bill Gates would suggest. Get a better cpu :)

Comment: @lunchmeat you're wrong. The standalone player is simply a wrapper for the same runtime that runs in the browser. Also it doesn't matter if multiple instances are open necessarily because if they're not on screen or in a separate tab, those flash instances will be paused and will only resume when visible.

Comment: @Ascension I've heard of people getting different framerates in the browser vs the standalone player, with browsers eating more CPU. Perhaps that's an issue with the wrapper itself, or the browser? As for the multiple instances thing - since version 9 (or 10) background tab swfs will run at a reduced framerate (2 frames per second) but anything in the foreground plays normally. Thus, two browser windows means two swfs playing at full framerate. All of that said, it's likely not his issue, but I would think it's still worth looking at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [SWFWire Debugger](http://www.swfwire.com/debugger).  Check the box that says **Show method entry**.  If you also check **Show method exit**, it will tell you how long each function took to execute.  The object graph might also help if you are creating and destroying objects often.

Comment: Then vote the man up! :)  Thanks for teh tip off Sean, I'd not heard of SWFWire before, looks great!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a Profiler, this answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357825/flash-actionscript-cpu-profiler) might help you out.